# Iterate st_intersection (sf) over factor levels

Tags: r, sf

I wrote a code using sf objects in order to count the number of points per category within cells. The code works well, but I would like to iterate over factor levels.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

region <- st_read(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"), quiet = TRUE)
PT <- st_sf(st_sample(region, size =100, type='random'))
PT$Class <- sample(LETTERS[1:4])
Mesh <- st_sf(st_make_grid(PT, cellsize = 0.2))
Mesh$ID <- seq.int(nrow(Mesh))

intersection <- st_intersection(Mesh, PT[PT$Class == "A",])
PT_result_A <- intersection %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  count()
```

The above works well to count the number of points with the "A" label inside each cell. In my original code/data I have this block as many time as I have categories, and I have a lot of categories.

Is it possible to automate the above to obtain the count of "A", "B", "C" and "D" without repeating the last block?

Comment: Just use tapply with length as the specified function.

Comment: Thx, I gave tapply some tries but with no luck so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following reprex should present three solutions to your problem. The last one is probably unnecessarily complicated but I think that the visualisation is nice.

```r
# packages
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(sf)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

# build data
region <- st_read(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"), quiet = TRUE)
points <- st_sf(
  data.frame(class = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 100, replace = TRUE)), 
  geometry = st_sample(region, size = 100, type='random')
)
mesh <- st_make_grid(points, cellsize = 0.2)
mesh <- st_sf(
  data.frame(ID = seq_along(mesh)), 
  geometry = mesh
)

# plot data
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(mesh, reset = FALSE, col = sf.colors(nrow(mesh), alpha = 0.25))
plot(points, pch = 16, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Count the number of points per cell using `tapply`

```r
tapply(st_geometry(points), points$class, FUN = function(x) lengths(st_intersects(mesh, x)))
#> $A
#>  [1] 1 4 2 0 4 3 0 1 1 6 0 0 0 3 0 0
#> 
#> $B
#>  [1] 0 3 1 0 1 4 3 0 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> $C
#>  [1] 2 4 3 0 5 1 4 2 5 5 0 0 1 1 0 0
#> 
#> $D
#>  [1] 3 3 1 1 3 1 5 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Count the number of points per cell using `dplyr`

```r
points %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  group_map(~ lengths(st_intersects(mesh, .x)))
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 1 4 2 0 4 3 0 1 1 6 0 0 0 3 0 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1] 0 3 1 0 1 4 3 0 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>  [1] 2 4 3 0 5 1 4 2 5 5 0 0 1 1 0 0
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>  [1] 3 3 1 1 3 1 5 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

`dplyr` + `group_nest` to create a map displaying the counts

```r
counts_per_cell_and_class <- points %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  group_nest() %>% 
  mutate(counts = lapply(data, function(df) as.character(lengths(st_intersects(mesh, df))))) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest(cols = counts) %>% 
  mutate(ID = rep(seq_len(nrow(mesh)), 4))

ggplot(st_as_sf(right_join(counts_per_cell_and_class, mesh))) +  
  geom_sf(aes(fill = counts)) + 
  geom_sf(data = points) + 
  facet_wrap(~ class, nrow = 1, ncol = 4) + 
  scale_fill_brewer() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
#> Joining, by = "ID"
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>